# Need help re: FFT output scaling

Tags: matlab, fft

I'm currently studying the following book: "Fourier Transform Spectroscopy Instrumentation Engineering", by Vidi Saptari. My question is related to the code below, based on the code from the book, Appendix C. The code below computes the interferogram of 3 waves with wavenumbers [cm-1] 5000, 10000 and 15000, respectively, and than performs an FFT to retrieve the information. The unscaled output has a magnitude of 1600, instead of 1.

```
clear;
% Sampling clock signal generation
samp_period_nm = 632.8 / 4; % sampling period in nm. 632.8 is the HeNe laser's wavelength
samp_period = 1 * samp_period_nm * 10^-7; % sampling period in cm. 
scan_dist   = 0.1; % mirror scan distance in cm. 
no_elements = floor(scan_dist/samp_period);
x_samp = 0:samp_period:samp_period*no_elements; %Vector of clock signals in cm
xn_samp = x_samp .* (1 + rand(1, length(x_samp)));
v1 = 5000;
v2 = 10000;
v3 = 15000;
arg  = 4 * pi * x_samp;
y   = cos(arg*v1) + cos(arg*v2) + cos(arg*v3) ;
total_data = 2^18;
no_zero_fills=[total_data - length(y)];
zero_fills=zeros(1, no_zero_fills);
%triangular apodization
n_y = length(y);
points = 1:1:n_y;
tri = 1 - 1/(n_y) * points(1:n_y);
y = y.*tri; %dot product of interferogram with triangular apodization function
y = [y zero_fills];   %zero filling
% FFT operation
fft_y = fft(y);
% fft_y = fft_y / n_y;
% fft_y = fft_y * samp_period;
fft_y(1) = [];
n_fft=length(fft_y);
spec_y = abs(fft_y(1:n_fft/2)); %spectrum generation
nyquist = 1 / (samp_period * 4);
freq = (1:n_fft/2)/(n_fft/2)*nyquist; %frequency scale generation
figure();
plot(freq, spec_y);   % plot of spectrum vs wave number
xlabel('Wavenumber [cm-1]');
ylabel('Intesity [V]');
```

By multiplying the result of the fft (fft_y) with dt = samp_period, as suggested [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/15770-scaling-the-fft-and-the-ifft), the peak is as 0.025.

Following [the same link's](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/15770-scaling-the-fft-and-the-ifft) second solution, by dividing fft_y by n_y (the length of y), the magnitude is 0.25.

Clearly, I'm doing something wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Normally you would need to divide by the number of elements in the FFT, N, to get correct scaling, although there can also be a factor of 2 to take into account if you're doing real-to-complex FFT and only using the first half of the output. Note that not all FFT implementations handle scaling in the same way, but the factor of N is the most common.

Comment: Hey Paul, I'm using Matlab's fft, and online it mentions this one does not provide any scaling. Now, before the FFT I'm doing apodization and zero padding, as recommended, so this will increase the number of points in the FFT by ~ 1000, from 2^14 to 2^18. By dividing with N, the peaks are at 6*10^-3, well below 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you're doing wrong here is expecting the peaks in the spectrum to be 1. According to Parseval's theorem of DFT the energy of the time domain signal is equal to the energy of the frequency domain signal divided by the lenght of the sequence N. You can check this in your example:

```
td_energy = sum( abs(y).^2 )
fd_energy = sum( abs(fft_y).^2 )
td_energy - fd_energy / length(y) % won't be exactly zero because you deleted the zero frequency bin.
```

So the peaks in your spectrum don't represent the *amplitudes* of cosine waves in the time domain but their *energy*. Also note at this point that the energy is lower than you might expect as you padded a lot of zeros.

In practice, the average power of a certain frequency is often of greater interest. Consider the following code example

```
t = linspace(-4*pi, 4*pi, 2^16);
N = length(t); % DFT length
y = cos(t); % single cosine wave
y_pow = sum( abs(y).^2 ) / N; % is 0.5
fft_y = fft(y);
fft_y_pow = (sum( abs(fft_y).^2 ) / N) /N; % is 0.5
figure; plot(abs(fft_y)./N);
```

The power is obtained by averaging the energy by the length of the sequence N. If you divide the spectrum by N you obtain the average power per frequency. In the above example you recognize a single peak with height 0.5 that represents the single cos wave of amplitude 1 (and hence power 0.5).

Personally, I prefer scaling MATLAB's FFT output by `1/sqrt(N)` and its IFFT output by `sqrt(N)`. In this way, the energy of the time and frequency domain sequence are always equal.

Comment: Hey Deve, thanks for the detailed answer.

I still don't understand it completely. According to the interference formula of a polychromatic source:

`I_ac(x) = sum(C(v_i)*cos(4*pi*x*v_i))`

where wavenumber **v_i** is between v_min and v_max, **x** is the optical path difference and **C(v_i)** is the intensity of the wavenumber v_i. In the example above, C(v_i) = 1 for all wavenumbers. 

So, according to the book, by performing an FFT over y, we should obtain the spectral distribution information, that is the **C(v_i)** for each v_i.

Comment: I think we would need more information to check this. "Spectral distribution information" is a vague term to me. From the FFT spectrum you can tell how strong a frequency component is compared to others.

Comment: Deve, this is basically a simulation of a [fourier transform spectrometer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform_spectroscopy), which  measures the absorption spectrum, i.e. intensity for each wavenumber in a polychromatic source of light (in this case, containing 3 wavenumbers) after passing through a medium. In this cases the light is not absorbed, thus I expect to have at the output the same intensity as at the input. The theory is explained in detail in the previous link. A nice simulation is presented [here](http://www3.wooster.edu/chemistry/analytical/ftir/default.html)

Comment: In none of the sources you provided it's said that the DFT of an interferogram produces a spectrum which shows the amplitudes of the different wavelength tributaries as peaks. The last slide of [this presentation](http://www3.wooster.edu/chemistry/analytical/ftir/default.html) is just a symbolic illustration, your spectrum will never look like this. Look at the [image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Spectrum_of_blue_flame.svg) in the Wiki article - of what unit is the intensity supposed to be? I think they just took the output of the DFT.

Comment: @Domi Also see [this question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3291/window-function-and-length-of-signal) on dsp.stackexchange for some more details on this topic.

Comment: thanks for the link. It shed some light. So the reason is the windowing, right?

Regarding the Wiki link, it states _This spectrum is not calibrated for intensity_.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the same energy in the IFFT input and ouput you have to multiply
the IFFT output (time signal) by sqrt(N) where N is the size of the transform.

here's the code :

same thing for the FFT (divide output by sqrt(N));
hope it helps
Felix

```
N = 4096;
Freq = randn(N,1)+1j*randn(N,1);
Time = sqrt(N)*ifft(Freq,N);
FreqEn = sum(real(Freq).^2 + imag(Freq).^2); 
TimeEn = sum(real(Time).^2 + imag(Time).^2);
```

TimeEn/Freq